# Why does f"{11: 2d}" not pad to 2 characters?

Tags: python, format-string, f-string

I'm using `Ipython 7.0.1` with `Python 3.6.9`

I want to right align numbers with the format string mini language. I use `1` and `11` as examples for 1 and 2 digit numbers which I want to pad to 2 characters total.

For zero padding everything works as expected, `>` is optional because it is the default:

```
In [0]: print(f"{1:02d}\n{11:02d}\n{1:0>2d}\n{11:0>2d}")                                         
01
11
01
11
```

But when I want to pad with spaces it also works as long as I leave the space out so that it defaults to space:

```
In [1]: print(f"{1:2d}\n{11:2d}\n{1:>2d}\n{11:>2d}")                                             
 1
11
 1
11
```

But If I explicitly type out the space, I am surprised by the result:

```
In [2]: print(f"{1: 2d}\n{11: 2d}\n{1: >2d}\n{11: >2d}")                                         
 1
 11
 1
11
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all in the documentation...

> format_spec     ::=  [[fill]align][sign]...
>
> If a valid align value is specified, it can be preceded by a fill character

Since both `fill` and `sign` can be `space` it would be ambiguous, and so `space` as `fill` must be followed by an `align`.

Here's how Python interprets your last line:

```
f"{1: 2d}"    #interpreted as sign therefore (accidentally) same effect  -> " 1"
f"{11: 2d}"   #interpreted as sign therefore a leading space is inserted -> " 11"
f"{1: >2d}"   #align is present, pad with ' '                            -> " 1"
f"{11: >2d}"  #align is present, pad with ' ' but number long enough     -> "11"
```